# Calculus with two variables

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\log(\pi \sigma/2)-x+\log(1+x^2/\sigma^2))=\frac{2x}{x^2+\sigma^2}-1,$$ where $x\ge0$ and $\sigma\ge 1$

Task: To find $x$ such that we have the maximum  $$(\log(\pi\sigma/2)-x + \log(1+x^2/\sigma^2))$$

Anyone can help with this(at the first glance, I know it is x=0, however I am not sure the standard procedure to prove it) ? appreciate!

Comment: but it must be $$\frac{2x}{x^2+\sigma^2}-1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function $f(x)$, to find the maximum you have to take $f'(x)$, then set $f(x) = 0$ and solve for $x$.

Notice that this will actually give you critical point(s) $x$, not necessarily those points are maxima or minima.

To have a maxima, once you found $x_0$ (critical point), it has to be

$$f''(x_0) < 0$$

Thou already have the derivative, now you have to solve it.

$$\frac{2x}{x^2 + \sigma^2} - 1 = 0$$

Hence

$$2x - (x^2+\sigma^2) = 0$$

With the condition $x \neq +\sigma$ and $x\neq -\sigma$.

Now it's a second degree equation:

$$x^2 + \sigma^2 - 2x = 0$$

$$x_{1, 2} = \frac{2\pm\sqrt{4 - 4\sigma^2}}{2}$$

$$\boxed{x_{1, 2} = 1\pm \sqrt{1 - \sigma^2}}$$

Those are your critical points.

Now take the second derivative:

$$f''(x) = \frac{2 (\sigma-x) (\sigma+x)}{\left(\sigma^2+x^2\right)^2}$$

It has to be $f''(x_{1,2}) < 0$.